# onclick Javascript failing to pass If Condition

Tags: javascript, onclick

What could be wrong with this code? I'm fairly new to javascript and I've been trying to debug on my own to no avail.

The  `alert('confirmed: ' + records[i].ENQ_Confirmed_with_Enbridge__c);` shows false but it won't pass the if condition so my counter isn't incrementing.

Same goes with `if(records[i].ENQ_QSC_Notified__c === false` even if the value of the field is false, it doesn't pass the condition as well.

```
var assPac = new sforce.SObject("ENQ_Assignment_Package__c"); 
var qscContact = '{!ENQ_Assignment_Package__c.ENQ_QSC_Contact__c}'; 
var status = '{!ENQ_Assignment_Package__c.ENQ_Status__c}'; 
var otherP = sforce.connection.query("Select 
              Id,ENQ_Confirmed_with_Enbridge__c,ENQ_QSC_Notified__c FROM 
              ENQ_QSR_Assignment__c where ENQ_Assignment_Package__c = 
              '{!ENQ_Assignment_Package__c.Id}'");
var records = otherP.getArray("records");

for(var i=0; i<records.length; i++){
alert('confirmed: ' + records[i].ENQ_Confirmed_with_Enbridge__c);
if(records[i].ENQ_Confirmed_with_Enbridge__c === false){
   alert('check');
   counter++;    
}
 alert('counter: ' + counter);
if(records[i].ENQ_QSC_Notified__c === false){
   records[i].ENQ_QSC_Notified__c = true;
   qscNotified.push(records[i]);
}

}
alert('qscNotified: ' + qscNotified.length);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it now with the help of reading this related question([Is there a bug in the way custom buttons handle checkboxes on related objects?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28128/is-there-a-bug-in-the-way-custom-buttons-handle-checkboxes-on-related-objects?rq=1)). 
So the boolean has to be enclosed in quotes, where I'm not used to. That was difficult to debug, though.

Comment: That is simply because you're getting a string representation of the result in your return from the apex. SFDCFox answer willl work great as it converts the string value to an actual boolean and compares to a boolean. Both approaches will work - however i must agree with his route being cleaner and less prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using getBoolean if you want to do a direct comparison:

```
if(records[i].getBoolean('ENQ_QSC_Notified__c') === false){
```

I'd probably recommend this approach for most normal situations.